# How to get CLLocationManager in my app

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

```
@class CLLocationManager;

@interface CLLocationController : NSObject 
{ 
   CLLocationManager *locationManager; 
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) CLLocationManager *locationManager;

@end
```

When i write above code is shows me following errors

error: CLLocationManager.h: No such file or directory 
warning: receiver 'CLLocationManager' is a forward class and corresponding @interface may not error: accessing unknown 'delegate' component of a property

Answer (score 18):

Why are you declaring your own classes with the CL prefix?

Also, the error has nothing to do with the code you showed; it refers to the `#import` line in your implementation file. You're probably doing something like this:

```
#import "CLLocationManager.h"
```

instead of the correct way:

```
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
```

Don't import individual headers from a framework directly—import its top-level header and let that give you what you need. If compilation is getting to take too long, move the `#import` to your prefix header and make sure you have “Precompile Prefix Header” turned on.

Answer (score 6):

Also, don't forget you have to actually add the CoreLocation framework to your app.  To do this, double click on your target, go to the first tab, and click the + button in the lower left.  This will bring up a list of available frameworks.  Find CoreLocation.framework, and click "OK".